# Export table rows directly to a csv file using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, export-to-csv

How do I export result of a sql query to a csv file without mapping to an object. Is there a direct way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve data from database using `IDataReader`, and in a loop write all it's fields to csv file.

Also you can use [csvhelper](http://csvhelper.com) to write csv.

Comment: Is this looping will cause any performance issue as I will have more than 3000 records each time

Answer (score 0):

You can directly handle this situation in data base.I mean directly import data into csv else you handle in code.